Flask and Flask-login not persisting login after redirect
Edit: The issue was fixed by adding “credentials: “include”” to the sign-up post on the front end.
I'm working on a project that incorporates a flask backend and a next.js frontend. When I sign up, it successfully creates a User in the database and is supposed to redirect to the index page, but the login session is lost after the redirect. I've tried multiple things but nothing has worked so far.
This is my auth file:
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash, jsonify, session
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from .models import User
from . import db, bcrypt, login_manager
from flask_login import LoginManager

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user)
            flash('Logged in successfully!', 'success')
            return jsonify({'message': 'User Successfully logged In', 'username': email})
        else:
            flash('Login failed. Check your credentials.', 'danger')
    return jsonify({'message': 'None'})

@auth.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        email = data.get('email')
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')
        existing_user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if existing_user:
            flash('Email already registered!', 'warning')
        else:
            hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')
            new_user = User(username=username, email=email, password=hashed_password)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            print(f'before session: {session}')
            login_user(new_user)
            print(f'after session: {session}')
            flash('Account created!', 'success')
            return jsonify({'message': 'User Successfully Created', 'username': username})
    return jsonify({'message': 'None'})

@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('Logged out successfully.', 'info')
    return jsonify({'message': 'Logged out successfully'})

@auth.route('/api/login_state', methods=['GET'])
def login_state():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return {'logged_in': True, 'username': current_user.username}
    else:
        return {'logged_in': False, 'username': ''}

# user_loader
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print(f"Loading user with ID: {user_id}")
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

And this is my front end page:

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from './SignUpForm.modules.css'

export default function SignUpForm() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        username: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const [loginState, setLoginState] = useState({ logged_in: false, username: '' });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchLoginState = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/login_state', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    credentials: 'include',
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    setLoginState(data);
                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to fetch login state');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching login state:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchLoginState();
    }, []);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData((prevData) => ({
          ...prevData,
          [name]: value,
        }));
      };

      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => input.classList.remove('error'));

        let hasError = false;

        if (!formData.email) {
            document.getElementById('email').classList.add('error');
            hasError = true;
        }
        if (!formData.username) {
            document.getElementById('username').classList.add('error');
            hasError = true;
        }
        if (!formData.password) {
            document.getElementById('password').classList.add('error');
            hasError = true;
        }

        if (hasError) {
            alert("All fields are required!");
            return;
        }
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/signup', {
                method: 'POST', // HTTP method
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData), 
            });
    
            
            if (response.ok) { 
                const result = await response.json();
                console.log(response)
                console.log('Success:', result);
                const resp2 = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/login_state', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    credentials: 'include'
                });
                const data2 = await resp2.json()
                console.log('Login state before redirect: ', data2);
                console.log(document.cookie)
                window.location.href = '/';
            } else {
                console.error('Error:', response.status, response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Network error:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div id='formContainer'>
                <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="formElement">
                        <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
                        <input type='email' id='email' name='email' value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="formElement">
                        <label htmlFor='username'>Username</label>
                        <input type='text' id='username' name='username' value={formData.username} onChange={handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="formElement">
                        <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
                        <input type='password' id='password' name='password' value={formData.password} onChange={handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="formElement">
                        <input type='submit' value='Create Account!'></input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

In the browser network tab after sending the request, I can see that the API calls are successful for signing up and it returns a session cookie. When it redirects to the home page, it attempts to check the login state but the line if current_user.is_authenticated always returns False for some reason.
This is the init file that creates the app for the flask backend:
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from datetime import timedelta
from flask_cors import CORS

db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'XXXXXX'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(days=7)
    CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, origins=['http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'])  # Allow requests from your Next.js frontend

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    return app


I'd appreciate any help. I have no idea what else to try, or why the user is returning as not authenticated, right after logging in. I also noticed that the load_user method is never being called for some reason, even though login_user() should be calling it.
